# Putting Chameleon on an SD card

Tags: sd-card

I am having trouble getting [Raspberry Pi Chameleon](http://betanews.com/2013/01/18/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-the-ultimate-emulator/) for my Raspberry Pi. I'm not really sure how I am supposed to transfer the downloaded file to the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital). How can I do it?

BTW: I have a [MacBook Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro).

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this tutorial](http://www.stefanopaganini.com/raspberry-pi-chameleon-overview-and-tutorial/), specifically the section titled "How to Install Chameleon on an SD Card."